# An inequality of real numbers

Tags: inequality

I am trying to prove the following inequality:

Given $a$,$b$ and $c$ are real numbers such that $a^2+b^2+c^2=1$
$$2(1+a)(1+b)(1+c) \ge abc$$
My approach:

$2(1+a)(1+b)(1+c)$

$=2+2(a+b+c)+2(ab+bc+ca)+2abc$

$=2+2(a+b+c)+(a+b+c)^2-(a^2+b^2+c^2)+2abc$

$=1+2(a+b+c)+(a+b+c)^2+2abc$

$=(a+b+c+1)^2+2abc$

I am stuck here. What should be the correct approach?

Comment: Aren't you done already? $(a+b+c+1)^2 + 2abc \ge 2abc$.

Comment: $a$, $b$, $c$ are real numbers, not necessarily non-negative.

Comment: Yes, but $x^2 \ge 0$, always.

Answer (score 2):

Not the neatest completion, but you can consider the sign of $abc$.
If $abc \geq 0$, then the required result follows.
If $abc < 0$, if suffices to show that $(1+a)(1+b)(1+c) \geq 0$.

Comment: You are right. Now it seems really a stupid question. I should have figured it out myself.